# iPhone Adhoc OTA download error

Tags: iphone, ios, ad-hoc-distribution, ota

I have developed a OTA app which I can able to download to my iPhone and iPad devices(version 3gs) through Adhoc over the air.But when I am tring to download to some other devices other than mine(4s)it shows "the app cannot be download at this time".I even added the udid of those devices in that provisioning profile.can anyone help what was the exact problem?I am struggling to find it out.

Answer (score 2):

After adding each UDID, you need to rebuild and reupload your app.

Comment: I have made some changes ,then after i can able to download my app through 3g but getting error when in wifi...please help soon...